# Recyclerview not updating in coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

hi I'm getting information from web with jsoup and coroutine and I want to show data in recyclerview
All the information is well received but the RecyclerView does not show anything and the view is not updated

```
fun myCoroutine(): ArrayList<DataModel> {
        val listx = arrayListOf<DataModel>()

        GlobalScope.launch { // launch new coroutine in background and continue
            Log.d("asdasdasd", "start")
            var doc: Document = Jsoup.connect("http://5743.zanjan.medu.ir").timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).ignoreHttpErrors(true).sslSocketFactory(setTrustAllCerts()).get()
            val table: Elements = doc.select("table[class=\"table table-striped table-hover\"]")
            for (myTable in table) {
                val rows: Elements = myTable.select("tr")
                for (i in 1 until rows.size) {
                    val row: Element = rows.get(i)
                    val cols: Elements = row.select("td")
                    val href: Elements = row.select("a")
                    val strhref: String = href.attr("href")
                    listx.add(DataModel(cols.get(2).text(),strhref))
                    Log.d("asdasf",cols.get(2).text())
                }
            }
        }
        return listx
}

 private fun getData() {
        itemsData = ArrayList()

        itemsData = myCoroutine()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        adapter = RVAdapter(itemsData)
    }
```

and this is oncreate

```
var itemsData = ArrayList<DataModel>()

        adapter = RVAdapter(itemsData)
        val llm = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        itemsrv.setHasFixedSize(true)
        itemsrv.layoutManager = llm
        getData()
        itemsrv.adapter = adapter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has numerous bugs (`getData`, for instance, never sets the adapter onto the `RecyclerView`), but the biggest issue is that you're not actually waiting for `listx` to be populated - you're returning it immediately before it's populated.  You need to either move the population of the adapter to the coroutine and run that part on the UI thread dispatcher, or use a callback, or dispatch it to the UI thread.  Launching a coroutine and returning immediately doesn't make the data get populated when something tries to use it.